# javascript deeper object functions

Tags: javascript, function, object

how do I achieve this with an object that has functions?

I would like to sometimes launch a function a simple way then other times i would like to launch with extra data and bypass the part that normally would happen.

like digging a little deeper...

```
myobj.ONEFUNC=function(data1,data2){
    var DIFF=function(data3){
        /*In here I need to use data1, data2 & data3*/
        /*If this happens don't do normal*/
        /*maybe*/return;
        }
    /*do normal code things*/
    }


myobj.ONEFUNC('data1','data2').DIFF('data3');

myobj.ONEFUNC('data1','data2');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for that call syntax to work, `ONEFUNC` must return a function.

```
myobj.ONEFUNC=function(data1,data2){
  var DIFF=function(data3){
    /*In here I need to use data1, data2 & data3*/
    /*maybe*/return;
  }

  /*do normal code things*/

  return {DIFF: DIFF};
}
```

"If this happens don't do normal" isn't going to work though.  `ONEFUNC` runs, returns an object containing the function you want to then run, and then `DIFF` runs.  So `DIFF` only runs after `ONEFUNC` is done.  So you can't change how `ONEFUNC` runs based on whether you also call `DIFF`.

---

Perhaps instead, you want chaining?  Chaining means each function on your objects returns itself, so that you can continue to call methods on that object.

```
myobj = {
  ONEFUNC: function(data1, data2) {
    this.data1 = data1;
    this.data2 = data2;
    // other stuff
    return this;
  },

  DIFF: function(data3) {
    this.data3 = data3;
    alert(this.data1 + this.data2 + this.data3);
    return this;
  }
};

mobj.ONEFUNC(1,2).DIFF(3); // alerts "6"
```

You still can't change how `ONEFUNC` runs after it ran though.  You may have to rethink why you need to that...

Comment: but if i don't call diff when i run ONEFUNC what happens?

Comment: +1. You to completely match original line: `return {DIFF:DIFF};` so you can use `.DIFF(..`

Comment: @BenMuircroft you can't change how `ONEFUNC` runs because anything you add to that statement operates on the _return value_ of `ONEFUNC`.

Comment: @BenMuircroft Sorry I don't understand your question.

Comment: I dont think chaining, because does that mean that ONEFUNC will always happen?

Comment: If you call `ONEFUNC` it will execute, always.  `ONEFUNC` has no way to know what's being done with the value it returns. This is weird and painful because it's a bad idea.  Whatever you are trying to do, I'll bet you a dollar there is a far more elegant way.  But it's hard to recommend anything based on the info you provided so far.

Comment: so rather then, I would have to have 2 separate functions inside ONEFUNC... myobj.ONEFUNC().DIFF() myobj.ONEFUNC.NORM()

Comment: in fact i would like to find 'A MORE ELEGANT WAY' to have a choice to do **one thing** or **more than one thing**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41788/discussion-between-ben-muircroft-and-alex-wayne)